# I am receiving the following error: expected identifier or '('

Tags: c, do-while, getstring

The error is referencing the following line of code:

```
tenant[i].name = get_string("Enter the residents name: ");
```

and has an arrow pointing at the period `.` between `tenant[i]` and `name`. I am not sure what I am missing.

```
typedef struct {
    string name;
    int apt;
} tenant;

int n;

int numres(void);

string nameres(int numres);

int apt(int numofres);

int main(void) {
    int numres(void);

    tenant tenants[n];

    string nameres(int n);

    int apt(int n);

    for (int m = 0; m < n; m++) {
        printf("Resident %s resides in apt# %i\n",
               tenants[m].name, tenants[m].apt);
    }
    return 0;
}

//this function prompts the user for the number of residents
int numres(void) {
    do {
        n = get_int("Enter the number of residents: ");
    } while (isalpha(n) != 0 || isspace(n) != 0);
    return n;
}

// this function prompts the user for the residents names.
string nameres(int numres) {
    int i = 0;
    do {
        tenant[i].name = get_string("Enter the residents name: ");
        return tenant[i].name;
        i++;
    } while (i < numres);
}

// this function prompts the user for the residents apt number
int apt(int numofres) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numofres; i++) {
        tenant[i].apt = get_int("Enter residents apt number: ");
        return tenant[i].apt;
    }
}
```

Comment: tenant is a type. tenants is a variable. You mistyped.

Comment: Once you fix the typo you'll have a bunch of other things to fix. `tenants` is a local variable in the `main` function, so where you try to use it in other functions it will not exist. `int numres(void);` is a forward declaration of a function, not a function call. To call the function you'd use `numres();`

Comment: That global `int n` is surely a mistake. It doesn't belong there.

Comment: Why is there a `return` that always fires inside the "loop" of your `nameres()` function? What is the purpose of that? This code doesn't make any sense.

Comment: This is the darker side of "refactoring" code when the basic implementation hasn't been shown to work to begin with...

Comment: There is no `string` type in C. Do you use some `cs50` header you did not show us or do you use C++?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in the code:

- the `string` type is not a standard C type, it is defined in `<cs50.h>` as a `typedef` for `char *`, which can be quite confusing. Make sure you include `<cs50.h>` and `<stdio.h>`.
- in the `main` function, you define `tenant tenants[n];`, an array with a length specified by a variable that has a value of `0`: this has undefined behavior, and the array cannot be used for anything.
- in the `main` function, you declare functions `int numres(void);`, `string nameres(int n);` and `int apt(int n);`. Such declarations should be made at the file scope, and indeed are done so already. You probably meant to call the functions instead, so you should write:

  ```
  int main(void) {
      numres();

      tenant tenants[n];

      nameres(n);
      apt(n);

      for (int m = 0; m < n; m++) {
          printf("Resident %s resides in apt# %i\n",
                 tenants[m].name, tenants[m].apt);
      }
      return 0;
  }
  ```

  But passing the value of `n` as a global variable is cumbersome and confusing. `numres()` should return the value and `n` should be a local variable.
- in `numres`, it does not make sense to test `isalpha(n) != 0 || isspace(n) != 0` because `n` is a number, not the value of a byte read from the input stream.  The function `get_int` already checks for valid input and returns a converted number, you should just check that the number is positive: `n > 0`.
- `nameres` should be defined as a `void` function and use a `for` loop for the case where `n` has the value `0`.
- in `nameres` and `apt` should receive `tenants` as an argument as this array is defined locally in `main`. The code should use `tenants` instead of `tenant`, which is a type name. This is the reason for your compilation issue. Using a `_t` suffix for the types is recommended to avoid such problems.
- in `nameres` and `apt` should should prompt for the name and apartment numbers of all residents, remove the `return` statements.
- using `while` or `for` loops instead of `do` / `while` loops allows for more concise code with explicit tests closer to the generating fact.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct tenant_t {
    string name;
    int apt;
} tenant_t;

int numres(void);
void nameres(tenant_t tenants[], int numres);
void apt(tenant_t tenants[], int numres);

int main() {
    int n = numres();

    tenant_t tenants[n];

    nameres(tenants, n);
    apt(tenants, n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Resident %s resides in apt# %i\n",
               tenants[i].name, tenants[i].apt);
    }
    return 0;
}

// this function prompts the user for the number of residents
// it returns the number which must be strictly positive
int numres(void) {
    for (;;) {
        int n = get_int("Enter the number of residents: ");
        if (n > 0)
            return n;
    }
}

// this function prompts the user for the residents names.
void nameres(tenant_t tenants[], int numres) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numres; i++) {
        tenants[i].name = get_string("Enter the residents name: ");
    }
}

// this function prompts the user for the residents apt number
void apt(tenant_t tenants[], int numres) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numres; i++) {
        tenants[i].apt = get_int("Enter residents apt number: ");
    }
}
```